# How to set "Enable scrolling" as default in Adobe Acrobat 11

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have Acrobat Adobe 11.0.07 for OSX and I can't find a way to set "Enable scrolling" (in "View" -> "Page Display" as a default option.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Accessibility > Always use Page Layout Style > Single Page Continuous

Comment: From @RevereGirl: A restart of your computer may be necessary for the changed setting to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I can scroll only by clicking the little finger pointer to toggle touch mode, and I need to do that every time I open a document.

I have no idea why touch mode has anything to do with showing the scrolling bar, but that's what works for me.